# Error connecting to memsql with mysql C connector

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector, singlestore

I'm trying to connect to memsql via mysql C connector:

```
MYSQL *connection = mysql_init(NULL);
mysql_real_connect(connection, HOST, USER, NULL, DBNAME, 0, NULL, 0);
```

but I get `"Error in server handshake"`.

Connecting from the terminal (`mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306`) works fine. I tried setting the root password, but nothing changes.

I also added `SSL_MODE_DISABLED` to `mysql_options()` and made sure SSL is disabled for memsql.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of the MySQL C connector are you using?  MySql changed the default authentication protocol in MySQL 8, so I would suggest using the older C connector (any version older than 8).  If you want to use the MySQL 8 connector then you will need to pass along default-auth=mysql_native_password in some fashion.

The same issue exists using the MySQL 8 C connector and connecting to an older version of MySQL (see https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90994).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was using the version 8.0, but changed it to an older one and now it seems to be working.